# Animating a view in a real time

Tags: xcode, animation, mapkit, swift5, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create animation that is connected to real time.

I have two points on my screen and an image moves between them. So for example I have an image that is at the Strat point at 12:00 and I want it to be at the end point at 12:10.

```
func animate_this_image(start: Date, end: Date, imageView: UIImageView, start_point: CGPoint, end_point: CGPoint) {
    let duration = end.timeIntervalSince(start)
    let frame = CGRect(x: end_point.x, y: end_point.y, width: 60, height: 60).offsetBy(dx: -30, dy: -30)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
        imageView.frame = frame
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want it to be connected to the actual clock. So for example if I close the view at 12:02 and open it at 12:09 I want the image to be at the correct place between the two point (roughly at the end). Instead at the moment the image starts again from the start point. That is happening because I just take the two dates and use the difference as the animation duration.

Anyone that has had similar problem or a suggestion on how I can solve this?

This is connected to a map. I have two points and a poly line between the points. I wanted an image to glide between the points. I could not figure anything easy with the map so I created a view on top of the map that has the image view on. I transfer the points from the map to the other view to get the start and stop points. Maybe there is a better way to do this by using the map?

Cheers,
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

This was easier than I thought... this is my solution

```
func animate_this_image(start: Date, end: Date, imageView: UIImageView, start_point: CGPoint, end_point: CGPoint) {
    // find the total duration and the time left until reaching next point
    let duration = end.timeIntervalSince(start)
    let time_left = end.timeIntervalSince(Date())
    // the percentage is used to calculate how far is left on the line
    let percentage = time_left / duration
    //calculate the correct point at this time
    let x_dist = (end_point.x - start_point.x) * CGFloat(percentage)
    let y_dist = (end_point.y - start_point.y) * CGFloat(percentage)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: end_point.x - x_dist, y: end_point.y - y_dist, width: 60, height: 60).offsetBy(dx: -30, dy: -30)
    // define end point
    let frame = CGRect(x: end_point.x, y: end_point.y, width: 60, height: 60).offsetBy(dx: -30, dy: -30)
    // Then animate it
    UIView.animate(withDuration: time_left) {
        imageView.frame = frame
    }
}
```